# oracle 12 c Document Store RDBMS VS NoSql

Tags: oracle, rdbms, document-store

I want to know oracle 12 c Document Store  RDBMS VS NoSql

I think that the Oracle 12c DocumentStore  works similarly to MondoDB(schemaless-database).
But today I heard a shocking story.

> Oracle12C database works similar to RDBMS. oracle12c document-store create a temporary schema and store data in database. So Oracle12c DocumentStore is not NoSql. Also, how to use Nosql as RDBMS service without separate installation? It just provides similar functionality, not Nosql.

and I said "That's one feature built into the ORACLE12C version, NoSql is correct."

No conclusion, I don't think I'm wrong, but I ask a question because I wanted to get an accurate answer. Please provide a answer or related documentation.

Comment: Why did you find that "shocking"?  And more importantly, what was the source?

Comment: Can you please state your question, clearly?